# How to emulate Pocket PC (PPC) 2003?

Tags: emulation, windows, windows-mobile

The OS is at least 17-18 years ago. Yet there is a lot of scattered information and dead ends, and no clarity on how to emulate Pocket PC 2003, the early precedent to Windows Mobile.

How to emulate Pocket PC (PPC) 2003?

Answer (score 5):

Note: The following method was found through trial-and-error and backtracking the steps the installers require. The emulation is done via **PBEmulator**, not vs_emulator / DeviceEmulator

1. (Recommended) Get a Windows XP VM. Windows 7 is possibly supported, but no solid evidence so far
2. Download and install eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0 - [download @ archive.org](https://archive.org/details/EMbeddedVisualC4.0)

   - Seemingly an abandonware. Notice you need the full package, not just the update
   - Requires a product key --> You'd need to acquire one somewhere (not too hard)
3. (Recommended) Update eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0 to SP4. [Download @ Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=16683)
4. Download the Microsoft Pocket PC 2003 SDK - [download @ archive.org](https://archive.org/details/PocketPC2003SDK)

   - Seemingly an abandonware. There are reports online that the package used to be on the Microsoft's website, yet was deleted
5. Install the main package, which is Microsoft Pocket PC 2003 SDK
6. Install "Windows Mobile 2003 Second Edition Emulator Images for Pocket PC - WWE"

   - Usually found within "Microsoft Pocket PC 2003 SDK", but can sometimes be found separately online
7. Go to Start - All Programs - Microsoft Pocket PC 2003 SDK - Pocket PC 2003 Emulator. It should start up the emulator. Enjoy!

Side notes:

- The PPC emulator uses PBEmulator, not vs_emulator / DeviceEmulator (Microsoft Device Emulator v3.0) - used for Windows Mobile 5/6 and Windows CE 5/6.

  - For unknown reasons, the OS images made for PBEmulator aren't compatible with Microsoft Device Emulator v3.0, and vice versa.
  - Seemingly, one key difference between them is that PBEmulator emulated x86 architecture, while Microsoft Device Emulator v3.0 emulates ARMv4/ARMv5